# Polyglossia changes the bold letters from algorithms

Tags: algorithms, bold, polyglossia, greek

I compile the tex document with XeLaTeX. When I put on my premable this `\setdefaultlanguage{greek}`, table of content and algorithms special words loses their bold letters and I got an output like that.
[image]

But I tried to compile if from *[www.overleaf.com](http://www.overleaf.com)* and the output was as it supposed to be...
[image]

This is the code. Any clue or general advice whould be appreciated and I am sorry for my poor English

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{xltxtra} % xunicode,fontspec,graphicx
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setromanfont{Times New Roman}
\setmonofont[Color={0019D4}]{Courier New}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\greekfontsf[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\usepackage[left=1.91cm,right=1.91cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}



\title{Τεστ}
\author{Όνομα}
\date{\today}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Απαιτείται:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Επιστρέφεται:}}
\algrenewcommand\textproc{}% Used to be \textsc, changes uppercase to function



\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\ALG@name}{Αλγόριθμος}
\makeatother



\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
Ελληνικά

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Excersice 4}\label{ex4}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Require int $n \geq 0$
\Ensure dividers of n
\Function{dividers}{int $n$}
\State $count\gets 1$;
\State Array[$\frac{n}{2}$];
\For{$i\gets 1;\quad i\leq \frac{n}{2};\quad i++\quad$}
\If{$n \mod i = 0$}
\State $Array[count]\gets i$;
\State count++;
\EndIf
\EndFor
\State $Array[count]\gets 0$;
\State \textbf{return} $Array$;\Comment{Returns the array terminated by 0}
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks ok for me. Add `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1 ` at the begin of the document and then check in the log-file which fonts are used. There should be lines like `Requested font "Linux Libertine O/B/OT:script=grek;language=dflt;" at 10.95pt` in the log. Side remark: I wouldn't use xltxtra, that is outdated. Load only fontspec.

Comment: I changed xlytrra to fontspec and inside the log filed I found a similar message and many more about `Linux Libertine`, but how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What does the log say about  which fonts are actually used?

Comment: I am not sure how to found that.

Comment: Then make the log available somehow.

Comment: its too long to make it available. Is the font used on acrobat reader the same?
In that case, it uses CMMI10, CMMI8, CMMI9,CMR10,CMR6, LinLibertineO and TimesNewRomanPSMT

Comment: The internet is full of file upload systems. Until now every one managed to find something to make a log available.

Comment: https://we.tl/t-C6yNru7I0I this is the link from weTransfer site

Comment: the log says that fontspec can't find the bold font, on my miktex it works fine. What happens if you use `\newfontfamily\greekfont{LinLibertine_R.otf}[Script=Greek,BoldFont=LinLibertine_RZ.otf]`?

Comment: It does compile with no errors and the expected output. Thank you very much for your time